# IntelliJ: Custom auto-correct/-complete entries

Tags: java, intellij-idea, autocomplete

I have IntelliJ (v2018.3.2 Ultimate Edition) and look for an option to define custom entries which, ideally, replace certain words with another statement, or otherwise let me Ctrl+Space exchange custom words with a statement.

In my specific case, typing `@null` should be replaced by `{@code null}`.

Is there such a feature, or what workarounds may be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use live template variables: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html .